# Fastest approach to compare 2 large arrays - large data

Tags: sql-server, nosql, bigdata

I have a dataset of about 10mm hashes. I need to allow people to compare a list of hashes against those to see if they match or not. Right now we use sql and basically scan it for each of the items in the guessing array. This worked for about 10K but users are needing to check a larger set, something like 200K hashes against a dictionary of 10mm hashes

what might be a good approach for this, in sql or nosql or other

--

for context on the intent, we manage a opt-out list and allow marketing managers to upload a sheet against it and we return a clean and nomail file.

Comment: What do you mean with "10mm"? 10 million or 10 million million (=10 trillion)?

Comment: What language / os are you planning to run this on?

Comment: Matt - any language is fine

Comment: Philipp - 10mm meant 10 million, weird habit, thanks for making me google it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can provide the search values in a table, a EXCEPT query is probably your best bet. That will get you all entries for table 1 (search values) that are not in table two (opt-out list). See my post here for EXCEPT examples: http://sqlity.net/en/1401/a-join-a-day-except/

If that is not an option because the search values are not in the database, create a memory resident hash table with all 10 million hash values and use that to determine if a given email is part of the list. Even if you have to build that table anew for each batch, it will be faster than sending 200k requests to the database.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the current solution cannot scale up, 
i.e. adding more memory, cpus, etc. to maintain a responsive 
solution that is desired by the users is no longer possible 
due to the increased load on the system.

One way to maintain responsiveness would be to implement a
scalable solution that can scale-out, i.e., distributing
the workload across multiple systems.

E.g. If you could have 10 systems each with a local copy
of the 10 million hashes in a nosql, then when a request
comes in to check for 200K hashes, the work could get
distributed across 10 systems each handling a request
to check for 20K hashes.

This is classic divide and conquer approach.

Pseudo code would be something like

```
while (1) {                   
    wait for a request to come in;

    for (j = 1; j < 10; j++) {
        spawn(system[j], 1/10 of the request for matching)
    }   

    wait for/collect responses from 10 systems

    return result;
}
```

The local copies on the systems would have to be kept consistent
when any changes such as add/delete are made.